# Type Into save file path of excel: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: uipath, rpa

I'm getting an UiPath error "**Type Into save file path of excel: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**"

And would like to know why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have ran the code `"_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` as can be seen below and it provides the correct output.

[image: Output]

Based on this it would suggest that the `csvName` variable/argument is not set.

As a suggestion add an Assign above to initialise the variable
[image: Suggestion]

Comment: Thanks. I will try that now.